# ng-view not showing anything in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

here is my angular app.

```
var MyApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

MyApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/RestChecker", {
        templateUrl: "templates/RestChecker.html",
        controller: "RestController"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})

var RestController = function($scope, $log, Rest){
    $scope.restMethod = "get";
    $scope.restURL="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/77";
    $scope.fetchRest = function(){
        Rest.getIt($scope.restURL, $scope.restMethod).then(function(response){
            $scope.response = response.data.body;
            $scope.PostTitle = response.data.title;
            $scope.status = response.status;
            $scope.method = response.config.method;
        },function(response){
            $scope.response = response.data.body;
            $scope.PostTitle = "";
            $scope.status = "";
            $scope.method = "abc";
        });
    };
}

MyApp.controller("RestController", RestController);
```

here is my html..

inside head section. inserted base href tag

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
 <ng-view></ng-view>
<body>
```

just before the end of body tag. its

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

            <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/responsive/responsive.js"></script>
            <script src="js/responsive/services.js"></script>
```

I dont know where the problem is. just wasted my half of day in figuring out solution. also in URL its showing

> `http://192.168.0.8:8000/ThemeTemplate.html#%2FRestChecker`

got to know %2f is nothing but forward slash..

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: also, there is a folder named templates in the directory where i am having this main template.HTML file.. inside templates folder there is this partial restchecker.html file.

Comment: What is the content of your template `RestChecker.html`? Just to debug, remove HTML5 mode, i.e comment this line `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use 'ui-router'.

doc: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Your url will be `/RestChecker`  why are you accessing to  `/ThemeTemplate.html#%2FRestChecker`?
Inject your `Rest`  here `['ngRoute']);`

`Rest.getIt` ???

Try `Rest.get` instead